# Unknown device in Debian GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, debian, gnu

What is XT device **/dev/xda** in Debian GNU/Linux? Could it have something to do with the IBM Personal Computer XT?

I saw it [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/etch/i386/apcs04.html.en) and nowhere else.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `/dev/xda` used to provide access to the first drive on an XT-style disk controller, using [the `xd` driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.18/source/drivers/block/Kconfig#L106). Linux itself has never been able to run on an IBM PC XT, but it was possible to use XT disk controllers in Linux-compatible systems with ISA slots.

All this is obsolete; the document you found describes Debian 4.0, which was released in 2007. The driver was [removed from the kernel in 2013](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ec8edc764efa51e5acf9193a8846a5a99399ceb8).